# Lifetime error in rust when use show-image crate

Tags: rust, lifetime, rust-crates

Can anyone tell what the lifetime error is in the following code? (simplified from my actual code) I've looked it over myself, but I can't figure out what is wrong or how to fix it.

```
use crate::hello_world_capnp::hello_world;
use capnp_rpc::{rpc_twoparty_capnp, twoparty, RpcSystem};
use futures::AsyncReadExt;
use futures::FutureExt;
use std;

pub async fn main() -> Result<(), Box<dyn std::error::Error>> {
    tokio::task::LocalSet::new()
        .run_until(async move {
            let stream = tokio::net::TcpStream::connect("").await?;
            stream.set_nodelay(true)?;
            let (reader, writer) =
                tokio_util::compat::TokioAsyncReadCompatExt::compat(stream).split();
            let rpc_network = Box::new(twoparty::VatNetwork::new(
                reader,
                writer,
                rpc_twoparty_capnp::Side::Client,
                Default::default(),
            ));
            let mut rpc_system = RpcSystem::new(rpc_network, None);
            let hello_world: hello_world::Client =
                rpc_system.bootstrap(rpc_twoparty_capnp::Side::Server);

            tokio::task::spawn_local(Box::pin(rpc_system.map(|_| ())));

            let mut request = hello_world.say_hello_request();
            request.get().init_request().set_name("name");

            let reply = request.send().promise.await.unwrap();
            let img = reply
                .get()
                .unwrap()
                .get_reply()
                .unwrap()
                .get_image()
                .unwrap();

            show_image::run_context(move || {
                let image = ImageView::new(ImageInfo::rgb8(800, 533), img.clone());
            });
            Ok(())
        })
        .await
}
```

The compiler error is

```
`reply` does not live long enough

borrowed value does not live long enough
```

Comment: Please paste the full error message as printed by the compiler, including line numbers, code extracts and compiler suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm making some assumptions, as not all the code is given.

It seems like `img` has the type `&[u8]`. It borrows from `reply`. `img` is then used in the closure given to `show_image::run_context()`. The problem is that, looking at [the docs](https://docs.rs/show-image/0.10.1/show_image/fn.run_context.html) for that function, it requires that the closure have the `'static` lifetime. But the closure captures `img`, which is not `'static`, and so you get the error.

A solution is to copy `img` to a new vec before `run_context()`:

```rust
let img = reply
    .get()
    .unwrap()
    .get_reply()
    .unwrap()
    .get_image()
    .unwrap()
    .to_vec(); // <--

show_image::run_context(move || {
    let image = ImageView::new(ImageInfo::rgb8(800, 533), img); // <--
});
```

Comment: That's right. `img` has the type `&[u8]`. I could clearly understand the way to solve this problem. Thank you for your quick and great answer!